# Add prefix to each element of array of strings

Tags: objective-c

Is there a quick way to add a string prefix to each element in array of strings?

Comment: without using for loop enumeration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a category of `NSMutableString`

```
@implementation NSMutableString (AppendPrefix)

- (void)appendPrefix:(NSString *)prefix {
    [self insertString:prefix atIndex:0];
}

@end
```

And then do:

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(appendPrefix:) withObject:@"some_prefix"];
```

`array` here is an `NSArray` of `NSMutableString`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit longwinded, but this should work:

```
- (NSArray *) prependArrayOfStrings:(NSArray*)originalArray prefix:(NSString*)prefix
{
  NSMutableArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
  for( NSString *currString in originalArray )
  {
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@%@", prefix, currString];
    [newArray addObject:newString];
  }

  return newArray;
}
```

---

```
// Somewhere else.
NSArray *originalArray = @[/*...*/];
// Fill in original array with array of strings
NSArray *newArray = [self prependArrayOfStrings:originalArray prefix:@"prefix"];
```